# How do I select only the first elements that match?

Tags: arrays, ruby, select, match

I'm using Ruby 2.4.  I want to select the first consecutive matching elemetns in an array, but then when I encounter an element that doesn't match, I want to stop selecting.  So if I want to find strings with a bunch of "a"'s, I could write this

```
2.4.0 :008 > arr = ["aaaa", "aaaaaaaa", "12345", "aaa"]
 => ["aaaa", "aaaaaaaa", "12345", "aaa"]
...
2.4.0 :010 > arr.select{|string| string.count('a') >= 3 }
 => ["aaaa", "aaaaaaaa", "aaa"]
```

but under my rules, I don't want to select the last "aaa" element because there was a non-matching element before it.  How do I modify what I have so that I only select the first matching elements?  Note that if my array were

```
["1111", "aaaaaa"]
```

I would want nothing returned since teh very first element in the array doesn't match my conditions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`#take_while` does what you want: https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-take_while

```
arr.take_while { |s| s.count('a') >= 3 }
=> ["aaaa", "aaaaaaaa"]
```